# Python file cache

Tags: python, file, caching

I'm creating some objects from files (validators from templates xsd files, to draw together other xsd files, as it happens), and I'd like to recreate the objects when the file on disk changes.

I could create something like:

```
def getobj(fname, cache = {}):
    try:
        obj, lastloaded = cache[fname]
        if lastloaded < last_time_written(fname):
           # same stuff as in except clause
    except KeyError:
        obj = create_from_file(fname)
        cache[fname] = (obj, currenttime)

    return obj
```

However, I would prefer to use someone else's tested code if it exists. Is there an existing library that does something like this?

**Update**: I'm using python 2.7.1.

Comment: Note that instead of repeating the code in the `except` clause inside your `if` statement, you could just `raise KeyError()` instead.

Comment: Nice mutable default argument!

Comment: @Amber Or use an inner function, which would probably be cleaner.

Comment: Contrary to @Katriel I don't like the mutable default argument here because I don't think they behave intuitively. Most of the time mutable default arguments change when you don't expect them to. In this case it is of course intended, but someone else reading the code may find themselves either (a) not understanding how the function works because it is counter-intuitive that cache will be anything else than {}, or (b), suspect that the function will fail at some point because it uses mutable default arguments.

Answer (score 5):

Your code (including the cache logic) looks fine.

Consider moving the *cache* variable outside the function definition.  That will make it possible to add other functions to clear or inspect the cache.

If you want to look at code that does something similar, look at the source for the [filecmp](http://docs.python.org/library/filecmp.html#module-filecmp) module:  http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/filecmp.py  The interesting part is how the [stat module](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html#module-stat) is used to determine whether a file has changed.  Here is the *signature* function:

```
def _sig(st):
    return (stat.S_IFMT(st.st_mode),
            st.st_size,
            st.st_mtime)
```

Answer (score 3):

Three thoughts.

1. Use [`try... except... else`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) for a neater control flow.
2. File modification times are notoriously unstable -- in particular, they don't necessarily correspond to the most recent time the file was modified!
3. Python 3 contains a caching decorator: `functools.lru_cache`. Here's the source.

   ```
   def lru_cache(maxsize=100):
       """Least-recently-used cache decorator.

       If *maxsize* is set to None, the LRU features are disabled and the cache
       can grow without bound.

       Arguments to the cached function must be hashable.

       View the cache statistics named tuple (hits, misses, maxsize, currsize) with
       f.cache_info().  Clear the cache and statistics with f.cache_clear().
       Access the underlying function with f.__wrapped__.

       See:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used

       """
       # Users should only access the lru_cache through its public API:
       #       cache_info, cache_clear, and f.__wrapped__
       # The internals of the lru_cache are encapsulated for thread safety and
       # to allow the implementation to change (including a possible C version).

       def decorating_function(user_function,
                   tuple=tuple, sorted=sorted, len=len, KeyError=KeyError):

           hits = misses = 0
           kwd_mark = (object(),)          # separates positional and keyword args
           lock = Lock()                   # needed because ordereddicts aren't threadsafe

           if maxsize is None:
               cache = dict()              # simple cache without ordering or size limit

               @wraps(user_function)
               def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
                   nonlocal hits, misses
                   key = args
                   if kwds:
                       key += kwd_mark + tuple(sorted(kwds.items()))
                   try:
                       result = cache[key]
                       hits += 1
                   except KeyError:
                       result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
                       cache[key] = result
                       misses += 1
                   return result
           else:
               cache = OrderedDict()       # ordered least recent to most recent
               cache_popitem = cache.popitem
               cache_renew = cache.move_to_end

               @wraps(user_function)
               def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
                   nonlocal hits, misses
                   key = args
                   if kwds:
                       key += kwd_mark + tuple(sorted(kwds.items()))
                   try:
                       with lock:
                           result = cache[key]
                           cache_renew(key)        # record recent use of this key
                           hits += 1
                   except KeyError:
                       result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
                       with lock:
                           cache[key] = result     # record recent use of this key
                           misses += 1
                           if len(cache) > maxsize:
                               cache_popitem(0)    # purge least recently used cache entry
                   return result

           def cache_info():
               """Report cache statistics"""
               with lock:
                   return _CacheInfo(hits, misses, maxsize, len(cache))

           def cache_clear():
               """Clear the cache and cache statistics"""
               nonlocal hits, misses
               with lock:
                   cache.clear()
                   hits = misses = 0

           wrapper.cache_info = cache_info
           wrapper.cache_clear = cache_clear
           return wrapper

       return decorating_function
   ```

Comment: I never knew about the `else` clause. Thanks for that (and all of this).

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a specific reason to use it as argument I would use cache as a global object

Comment: Valid, it was more an act of whimsy while composing in the SO window.

Comment: well, one reason is for performance.  the whole purpose of a cache is to improve performance, and local variable lookups (including default arguments) are faster by a modest amount compared with global lookups.  That said, this pattern is a great way to trip up future generations that aren't already familiar with this language quirk, and as you say, a global *should* be preferred for its explicitness when performance isn't of *utmost* importance.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy the usual idiom is `def foo(cache=cache):` to copy global variables into the local scope.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy I would say that the performance of global variable is pretty good comparing at a file seek