# Accessing single ASCII file by multiple codes slows down

Tags: python, bigdata, ascii

I have a large ASCII file that gets accessed by multiple python codes. I noticed that it slows down the codes (although it may not be the same memory location). Is there a clever way to access it in python without slowing down(other than creating multiple instances of the file)?

Comment: How big is the file size? `slows down the codes` can mean different things... There are multiple  processes that read the file nearly at the same time? Is this your situation?

Comment: Multiple codes as in different python codes access the same file.  The File is nearly a GB.

Comment: If it were in the same python module, i'd say `functools.lru_cache` <https://stackoverflow.com/a/9854893/1758363> could be helping. Putting file data to local database is another direction, but it may be a lot of work.

Comment: Have you tried making a separate copy of the file? Does that work?

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak interesting approach. Like you said seems like a lot of work

Comment: @JoshLee on my Mac it seems to work. Although I doubt it is dependent on the OS. File system to be precise

Comment: Another simple truth it might even work faster on a SSD, rather than HDD. So it is not just os level. )